# Projecting Anonymous to Entities not mapping navigation Property

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

My Table Structure is like this:

- Table Department has one to one relationship with Table Employee
- Table Employee has one to many relationship with Table Projects
- Table Projects has one to many relationship with Table Issues
- Table Employee has one to many relationship with Table Issues also.

**Note: There is a join table "EmployeeProjects" (employeeid, projectid). As this table is just a reference table, it is not mapped with EF and no model is generated for it**

```
var iQurableResult = DataContext.Department
                         .Include("Employee")
                         .Include("Employee.Projects")
                         .Include("Employee.Projects.Issues") 
                         .Where(filter => filter.IsSelected && filter.filterId == filterId)
                         .Select(x => new
                           {
                                dep = x,                                         
                                emp = x.Employee.
                                projects = x.Employee.Projects.Where(g=>g.Id==10)
                                //Project the 
                                _issues = x.Employee.Projects.Where(g=>g.Id==10).Select(x=>x.Issues)
                           }).ToList();
```

At this point, I'm getting data in `iQurableResult` and the filtered data is fetched in the anonymous list.

When I try to project them into an entity, I'm not able to get the `Employee`'s projects. The code is below.

```
 var TableBList = iQurableResult.Select(y=>y.dep).ToList();
```

**My Findings**

I assume while projecting, `Employee` couldn't find relationship with table `Projects` hence its not mapped, but Table Issues is mapped in Table Employee.

**How is it that I should fetch data to relate with Employee and Projects?**

Comment: Are you saying that the `Department` in `TableBList` doesn't contain the employee's projects, but the anonymous type is fine? The question is difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I'm getting `Department` , `Department.Employee` and `Department.Employee.Issues` but i'm unable to get `Department.Employee.Projects`.  

The anonymous type seems to be working fine.

Comment: Using the string version should work, but since you have a mix of references and collections, maybe you could try the other syntax shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx#remarksToggle

Comment: You also shouldn't need three include statements, the last one should work for all three levels...or something like `.Include(d => d.Employee.Projects.Select(p => p.Issues)`.

Comment: @jjj, i will try this and update you asap

Comment: @jjj Thanks for the edit, I tried with include statement using lambda but still the same result.

Comment: In that case, maybe it's the class definition or model configuration? Would you be able to share that?

Comment: @jjj This is my configuration of DbContext 

`this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`